# Shuffle some sequence of List in Scala

Tags: scala, list, random, sequence, shuffle

I'm using `scala.util.Random`, then I know how to shuffle a list. It's very useful to randomize an order inside Array list, for example:

```
val List(a, b, c, d) = Random.shuffle(List(1,2,3,4))
it will result

a = 1
b = 3
c = 2
d = 4
```

the result of a, b, c, d could be any random value between 1 to 4.
But the thing is we can't do this:

```
val a:List = List(1,2,Random.shuffle(3,4,5))
```

please share if you guys have any clue for this case. If no, please explain why.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you have against `1 :: 2 :: Random.shuffle(List(3,4,5))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val a:List = List(1,2,Random.shuffle(3,4,5))` this line would give type error

*Reason*

Shuffle does not take var args and also List apply method does not take both elements and List as arguments simultaneously. This is how shuffle is declared in Standard Library.

```
 def shuffle[T, CC[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]](xs: CC[T])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[CC[T], T, CC[T]]): CC[T] = {
    val buf = new ArrayBuffer[T] ++= xs

    def swap(i1: Int, i2: Int) {
      val tmp = buf(i1)
      buf(i1) = buf(i2)
      buf(i2) = tmp
    }

    for (n <- buf.length to 2 by -1) {
      val k = nextInt(n)
      swap(n - 1, k)
    }

    (bf(xs) ++= buf).result()
  }
```

Instead do this

```
val a = List(1, 2) ++ Random.shuffle(List(3, 4, 5))
```

If you want more friendly API just declare an implicit like this

```
implicit class ListUtils[A](list: List[A]) {
  import scala.util.Random
  def addShuffling(xs: A*) = list ++ Random.shuffle(xs.toList)
}
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> import scala.util._

scala>  implicit class ListUtils[A](list: List[A]) {
     |       def addShuffling(xs: A*) = list ++ Random.shuffle(xs.toList)
     |     }
defined class ListUtils

scala> List(1, 2).addShuffling(3, 4, 5)
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 5, 3, 4)
```

Vector would be better for long lists. Use vector implementation for long lists

```
implicit class VectorUtils[A](vec: Vector[A]) {
   def addShuffling(xs: A*) = vec ++ Random.shuffle(xs.toVector)
}
```

**Scala REPL**

```
implicit class VectorUtils[A](vec: Vector[A]) {
      import scala.util.Random
      def addShuffling(xs: A*) = vec ++ Random.shuffle(xs.toVector)
    }

    Vector(1, 2).addShuffling(3, 4, 5)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class VectorUtils
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: This is correct, so the reason is because Random.shuffle only associated with List?

Comment: @DedenBangkit edited the answer with implicit idea .. just check

Comment: sure @pamu, The implicit idea is so genius! Thank you! you just answered my question.

Comment: @DedenBangkit  edited the answer Please check. Use Vector instead of List. Vector append is more efficient than list append

Comment: but why? is it because the list doesn't work with parallel algorithms?

Comment: @DedenBangkit no... appending to list is `O(n)` operation but appending to vector is `O(1)` operation